# NSFetchedResultsController with UILocalizedIndexedCollation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm implementing custom contact app where it supports multiple localization and now i'm stuck on Chinese characters sorting and indexing, i have seen couple of stack overflow blogs where people are suggesting to use UILocalizedIndexedCollation to solve this issue, but none of them works due to FRC is not well connected to UILocalizedIndexedCollation hence i see NO data when i switch back from Chinese mode to english mode on device.I have used transient property to  solve this issue it works in chinese mode and failed to fetch data when device in English mode.

```
-(NSString *)sectionIdentifier {

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    NSUInteger index = [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForObject:self
                                                                collationStringSelector:@selector(name)];
    NSString *sectionId = [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:index];
    NSLog(@"secKey = %@, value = %@", sectionId, self.name);
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    return sectionId;
}
```